# Swift 2.0 GET Request JSON

Tags: ios, json, get, request, swift2

This is my first time coding for iOS, actually my first week and I'm having a hard time coding on Swift 2.0, all the tutorials I can find on internet that might helped me are on Swift 1.0, and everything is so different, currently I'm trying to create a register/login system through an App. And I need to do it using GET parameter.

I'm capturing this 3 values successfully:

```
let nombre = userNameTfd.text!
let email = userEmailTfd.text!
let password = userPasswordTfd.text!
```

BUT when it comes to all the networking thing, nothing.
Lets say the URL is `www example com/example.php` and the values I'm sending are `&funcion=registra_usuario&nombre=\(nombre)&email=\(email)&password=\(password)`

In advance, thank you very much, this means a whole lot to me.

PS: I tried youtube com/watch?v=a5pzlbBnfYg (Which the tutorial doesn't teach you how to do networking).

youtube com/watch?v=4YDkJgZCoQs (Which is POST method)

youtube com/watch?v=v9bsZvHuQYI&list=PLPmuYoVHNtc-FXLPSIcG-w6f-3B_ezoMb (Which is swift 1.0 :( )

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you be more specific with the output you are getting when you try the `network thing`, along with what the `network thing` is? This will help people answer your question.

Comment: Thanks mate @mjkaufer !!! This is meant to be working for POST method, but I need to use GET :( 
`Optional(<>) Optional(<>) example.com/userGestion.php?&funcion=registra_usuario&nombre=aaa&email=aaa&passw‌​ord=aa Optional()` 
That is the output I'm getting, the example is a fake url btw